# How do I export large Visio 2010 drawing to PDF? Only part of the drawing is being exported

Tags: microsoft-visio, drawing

I have a relatively big drawing. When trying to save it as a PDF, I am only getting part of the total drawing.

How do I get the whole drawing to export?

Comment: Do you have anything selected when you try to export?

Comment: How do you export to PDF? What do you get?

Comment: Nothing selected @T.J.L.

Comment: - save as PDF ... got part of the drawing in PDF file @SPRBRN

Comment: Do you have any layers set to No Print? Are any of the shapes set to No Print?